# Sort child documents

Tags: solr

In Solr, how can I sort the child documents by score? As I tested, it seems to be only possible to sort the documents and not the child documents that are retrieved inside the parent document.

I have the following document:

```json
{
    "id": 0,
    "type": "parent",
    "name": "Arnold",
    "_childDocuments_": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "child",
            "field": "foo bar"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "type": "child",
            "field": "foo baz"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "type": "child",
            "field": "bar baz"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "type": "child",
            "field": "foobar baz bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to filter by `foo baz`. I'm using:

```
q= {!parent which=type:parent}
fl= *, [child parentFilter=type:parent childFilter="field:foo OR field:baz"]
score= score desc
```

Since ID 2 is `foo baz`, I would expect to see this one as the first child document retrieved, but I'm seeing ID 1 `foo bar` as the first one because ID 1 was the first one to be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the [[child] transformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html#TransformingResultDocuments-_child_-ChildDocTransformerFactory), you can use the [[subquery] transformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html#TransformingResultDocuments-_subquery_).

```
q= {!parent which=type:parent}
fl= *, my_childs:[subquery]&my_childs.q=field:foo OR field:baz&my_childs.fl=*, score
```

Results in:

```js
"response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
        {
            "id":"0",
            "type": ["parent"],
            "name": ["Arnold"],
            "_version_": 1603334242311340032,
            "name_str": ["Arnold"],
            "type_str": ["parent"],
            "my_childs": {
                "numFound": 4,
                "start": 0,
                "docs":[
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "type": ["child"],
                        "field": ["foo baz"],
                        "field_str": ["foo baz"],
                        "_version_": 1603334242311340032,
                        "type_str": ["child"],
                        "score": 1.0998137
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "type": ["child"],
                        "field": ["foo bar"],
                        "field_str": ["foo bar"],
                        "_version_": 1603334242311340032,
                        "type_str": ["child"],
                        "score": 0.7261542
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "type": ["child"],
                        "field": ["bar baz"],
                        "field_str": ["bar baz"],
                        "_version_": 1603334242311340032,
                        "type_str": ["child"],
                        "score": 0.3736595
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "4",
                        "type": ["child"],
                        "field": ["foobar baz bar"],
                        "field_str": ["foobar baz bar"],
                        "_version_": 1603334242311340032,
                        "type_str": ["child"],
                        "score": 0.31387395
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a tradeoff in performance here. As per my understanding, [child] only gets executed within the boundaries of the child docs for a given parent. Whereas [subquery] gets executed across the index.