# Sort documents by nested object field in Solr

Tags: solr

I have documents like

```
        "name":"test",
        "_version_":1667998128851124224,
        "_root_":"test",
        "files":
        {
          "name":"<random_string>_test",
          "fileName":"test.html",
          ...
          "_nest_parent_":"test",
          "_version_":1667998128851124224,
          "_root_":"test"}},
```

I need sort documents by field `fileName` in nested documents (assuming I have only one nested obj in each doc). How's that possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856345/sort-child-documents

Comment: @MatsLindh I don't need sort child documents, I need sort documents by child's field.

Comment: Ah, good point. A possible strategy is shown here: https://blog.griddynamics.com/how-to-sort-parent-documents-by-child-attributes-in-solr/ - if this is something you're going to do a lot (i.e. it's performance relevant), I'd probably attempt to make it resolve when indexing (i.e. promote the sorting value to the root document) to avoid having to make the join each time.

Comment: @MatsLindh yeah, I have noticed that post, unfortunately it didnt work on my side ( tried dozens of diff combinations). May I ask you to show me sort example with my document structure? I tried - {!parent which='-_nest_path_:* *:*' score=max v='+_nest_parent_:* +{!func}fileName'} desc

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve the sort by child field in this scenario:

1. using what @MatsLindh already proposed in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62410977/sort-documents-by-nested-object-field-in-solr/71385252#comment110400068_62410977) above

```
    {
      "query": "*:*",
      "limit": 10,
      "filter": [
        "{!parent which=\"path:1.document\"}path:\"2.comment\""
      ],
      "fields": ["id"],
      "sort": "{!parent which=path:1.document score=max v='+path:2.comment {!func}fileName'} desc"
    }
```

2. using [childfield](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/function-queries.html#childfield-field-function) syntax

```
    {
      "query": "*:*",
      "limit": 10,
      "filter": [
        "{!parent which=\"path:1.document\"}path:\"2.comment\""
      ],
      "fields": ["id"],
      "sort": "childfield(fileName, {!parent which=path:1.document v=path:2.comment}) desc"
    }
```